# how to centralizer element in div from CSS?

Tags: html, css, division, divide

There is a class named `gdiv` in my style sheet which refer to the general `div` condition. 
I can change my text alignment from `gdiv`. but  can not change alignment of everything like `div` inside `div`. How can I align everything?

Comment: And your code here ?

Comment: Put on your code below so we can solve your doubts, this way we are blindly guessing

Answer (score 0):

*I think the best way to align the items to the center of your div, is to use flexbox*

```
.gdiv {
   display: flex; /* just to set it to flex box */
   justify-content: center; /* to align the items horizontally in the div */
   align-items: center; /* to align the items vertically in the div */
}
```

if you want to align the DIV itself by its parent, you can use this code in the parent;

*If what you want to align is a text, you can just use:*

```
.gdiv {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

If you're beginner, i highly recommend you to study flexbox and grid in css!

Comment: Thanks man. This works perfectly <3

Answer (score -1):

It is quite hard to give a solution without code. 
But flexbox should center everything inside a div, even other divs.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Thanks man. it works now

Comment: No worries. If your problem is solved I‘d be happy if you marked ma answer as helpful. Thanks